# Adding security credentials to SOAP message

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, visual-studio-2015

I need to add a username and password to the http header of a soap message.

I've been following this guide [How to: Add Security Credentials to a SOAP Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819938.aspx)

but it seems to be severely outdated, I tried to implement the changes it suggests and I ended up crashing visual studio, and killing the web server in iis.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, .net frameword 4.5.1.

```
string Artifact = Request.QueryString["SAMLart"];

                try
                {
                    GetAssertionClient client = new GetAssertionClient();

                    UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(settings.GetValue("NetsMID", 2), settings.GetValue("NetsPass", 2), PasswordOption.SendHashed);

                    SoapContext requestContext = client.RequestSoapContext;
                    requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);

                    RequestType type = new RequestType { ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType3[1] };
                    type.ItemsElementName[0] = ItemsChoiceType3.AssertionArtifact;
                    type.Items = new object[] { Artifact };

                    ResponseType resp = client.getassertion(type);
```

this is the code I'm running, of course this is with the modifications to the GetAssertionClient. I had tried to use ClientCredentials earlier, but the response I got from the other side was that mid and password were not included in the post. with this setup the program, visual studio and webserver dies completely, had to reboot computer when it happened.
did not however have such a dramatic effect second time I tried it, but visual studio still flopped out with ww3w or whatever it's called crashing.

the base of my problem is that the wsdl I used to bind this webservice does not include information about authentication so I need to hack that together manually. Help me, I'm stuck.

edit1:
I changed the code according a suggested solution below.

```
string Artifact = Request.QueryString["SAMLart"];

                try
                {
                    using (var client = new GetAssertionClient())
                    {
                        using (new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client.InnerChannel))
                        {
                            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",
                                Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", settings.GetValue("NetsMID", 2), settings.GetValue("NetsPass", 2)))));

                            RequestType type = new RequestType { ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType3[1] };
                            type.ItemsElementName[0] = ItemsChoiceType3.AssertionArtifact;
                            type.Items = new object[] { Artifact };

                            ResponseType resp = client.getassertion(type);
```

when I reach client.getassertion(type); I get the following exception:

```
2016-12-16 14:34:10 The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state. CommunicationObjectFaultedException mscorlib    
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.
```

the rest of the stack trace didn't make it in the log. but is there something I missed to implement here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an authentication token, or any custom headers to the request using the following approach.

```
using(var client = new SoapService.ServiceClient()){
   using(new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client.InnerChannel)){
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", 
           Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(String.Format("{username}:{password}", Username, Password))));
       // Call/Invoke service here
   }
}
```

In your SOAP service you can then access the added header. In case it is WCF then you can simply access that via `HttpContext.Current.Request.Header`". I recommend you to encrypt the header value anyway, because if it the request gets intercepted, the login will be compromised.

Comment: I am required to send the username and password in base64.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this :)

Comment: one question, SoapService.ServiceClient(), I'm guessing I should replace these with the GetAssertionClient()? or how do I go about invoking getassertion and having the header of that message changed?

Comment: @inifus: Yes that's right, you should replace it with your own client. Then you can invoke your service like `var res = await client.GetPersonAsync(...)`

Comment: I got an exception. The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state. did I miss something?